# jumps line in an inverted phrase c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I made a method to reverse the words of a phase, but my text file contains several lines.
Then, the result display is in a line.
I want to reverse every sentence in a line
my file contains

```
hello i am fine 
GoodBye friends
```

the result shows me:

```
GoodBye friends fine am i hello
```

I want to display:

```
fine am i hello
friends GoodBye
```

Code:

```
std::ifstream file("test.txt");
std::string content;
std::vector<std::string> numbers;
std::string line;

while(file >> content) 
    numbers.push_back(content);
for(int i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    std::cout << numbers[i] << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: You mis-tagged your question.

Comment: Where did `brakes` come from?

Comment: why do you call your vector `numbers`?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything to detect line breaks.

Comment: Read a line from the file with `getline()`, turn that line into a `std::stringstream`, reverse the words in the stream, print them followed by a newline. Repeat until you get to the end of the file.

Comment: you might be interested in [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: Yes, I know that getline to display all the lines, I can't reverse the words if there is a jumping line, I used getline but it shows me that the first 3 letters lol thank you :)